# Catch NameError during function declaration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dsl

I am trying to build an embedded DSL in Python, which involves some customized type that the identifier not in the scope of Python like:

```
@convert_to_dsl
def func(a: ExternType):
    return a
```

`convert_to_dsl` will parse the function and convert it to my DSL. But, Python will raise `NameError` since `ExternType` is not in current module during the function declartion.

I am wondering how to solve this.

I import those `ExternType` as a workaround, but I don't like it since there are many identifiers and they will pollute the current module.

Is it possible to modify `covert_to_dsl` as a context manager which will handle the thrown error? (It seems impossible that the function declaration happens before the decoration.)

Or is there any way to override the default error handling in Python so that I can avoid throwing the `NameError`?

Comment: Can't you import `ExternType`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, I use this as a workaround, but I don't like it since there are many identifiers which will pollute the current module.

Comment: `import your_module as ym` then `ym.ExternType`? It's hard to say without full context, but ignoring a `NameError` in a case like this strikes me as an XY problem.

Comment: "It seems impossible that the function declaration happens before the decoration" is unfortunately for you exactly how function decorators work — so you can't do what you want by making  `convert_to_dsl()` a context manager. Embedding another language inside Python will likely require the storing the DSL code in a string.